# Bit / Byte Confusion on Binary Digits

Tags: byte, bit

So I Heard that one character is a byte. But then I went to a website which measures text capacity,(Making website) and I typed in a 1. It showed on the byte count 1 byte. 8 bits = 1 byte, right? I thought 8 binary digits made 1 character. How can a 1 be a byte and a bit at the same time?

Comment: Why do you think the character 1 you typed would only take 1 bit to store?

Comment: How many bits do you think a different character, such as `G`, might take to store?

Comment: What you type is character '1', not a value of variable length numeric data type in 1-bit alignment system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, the number of bits per character is not so simple but there are most definitely 8 bits per byte.

The number of bits/bytes per character will vary depending on your system and the character set.

Original ASCII was 7bits per character.

That was extended to 8bits per character and stayed there for a very long time.

These days, with Unicode, you have variants that are 8, 16 and 32 bits (1, 2 and 4 bytes) wide.  Were the 8 bit variety corresponds to ASCII.

The character 1 is represented by binary 00110001b which is 8 bits thus 1byte.  The actual binary number 1b would be at a minimum 00000001b which represents a special character not the character 1.

Hopefully this helps.